# Penrose graphical notation with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw a tensor network like this using TikZ? 
[image]

Perhaps adding some words on them.

[image]

I'm very comfortable with LaTeX, but still a noob to TikZ. I will draw these kinds of shape extensively, and hope to know a template on them. Thanks!

**EDIT**

This is what I've done so far. I'm not sure how to connect line at specified border, the correct way of placing node (relative position or coordinate?), and how to put tokens at the specified positions.

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    triangle/.style = {regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, draw=black, fill=green!60!black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2cm},
    border rotated/.style = {shape border rotate=180},
    rectangular/.style={fill=brown!80!black, rectangle, rounded corners = 5pt, draw=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=4.5cm, minimum height=1cm},
    square/.style={fill=blue!60!black, rectangle, draw=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size = 1cm}
]

    \node[square] (1) {};
    \node[triangle, border rotated] (2) [below left = 1cm  of 1] {};
    \node[triangle, border rotated] (3) [below right = 1cm  of 1] {};
    \node[rectangular] (4) [below=3cm of 1] {};
    \node[square] (7) [below = 7cm of 1]{};
    \node[triangle] (5) [above left = 1cm  of 7] {};
    \node[triangle] (6) [above right = 1cm  of 7]{};

    \draw (2.35) -- +(0,0.2) -- (1);
    \draw (2.145) to [bend right=45] (5.215);
    \draw (3.145) -- +(0,0.2) -- (1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! TikZ has extensive documentation and there are copious examples available. What have you got so far? You are more likely to get useful help if you post something and ask about a specific problem. It isn't clear what you have in mind by a `template` but right now this looks like a do-all-these-for-me question. You may or may not get lucky and somebody answers, but the question is not really a fair one. You might look at `tikz-cd` or at the `chains` library, for example. And why are you so set on TikZ if you don't know anything about it anyway? Why not an alternative?

Comment: If you don't want to take the time to learn how to draw images, you can always include them as external images using `graphicx`. Or you can export TikZ code from Inkscape, for example. (It isn't very editable, but if you don't need to modify it, it should be fine.)

Comment: Is [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97507/typesetting-inline-penrose-cvitanovic-tensor-diagrams-birdtracks?rq=1) related?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm just kind of intimated by the 880 page of TikZ manual. If you know what chapters to look into for these functionality, I will be very grateful.

Comment: If you don't know anything about TikZ, start with one of the tutorials. Most of the manual won't be relevant and what is won't be obviously relevant until you need it, so there's no point in reading it anyway. Better still, huge chunks of it will be *obviously* irrelevant. It is really a bunch of manuals thrown together and would be better split up.

Comment: However, if your copy has 'only' 880 pages, you have an outdated TeX installation and probably TikZ 2.1. You would be well advised to update. Then maybe look at tutorials 1 and 5 in part I.

Comment: You could have a look at the `www.texample.net` site and browse through the many examples to find some from which you could elaborate to draw your diagram.

Comment: The big question is how many of these are you going to do?  If many, you might want to create node shapes and connect them like a circuit diagram.  If only a few, use standard shapes and locate attachment points using calc.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I take it 'many' from the question. But the initial problem is to learn a little bit about the basics of TikZ regardless of what the OP does next. Even if somebody here provides code for the shapes, using them 'extensively' will still require getting to grips with relevant parts of the package. That's why I suggested starting with a couple of the basic tutorials just to get a sense of how a picture works, really.

Comment: Thanks for posting some code! Please post complete examples, especially when using additional libraries/packages. I've completed your code in one way. If it doesn't reflect your usage, please edit it appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain I understand all of the 3 points you've asked about. For example, I'm not sure what 'tokens' refers to, though I'm guessing the filled black circles.

Generally, relative positioning makes it easier to modify code later. For example, it is easier to add new things into the diagram and have other things auto-adjust. But it is really a question of what works best in a particular case. Often, absolute positioning is quicker to do for a one-off, for example, although it makes the code less flexible.

I've renamed `triangle` to `triangular` to avoid overwriting the `triangle` shape.

The code below shows one way to:

- connect the triangles from the appropriate points;
- connect the triangles to the rectangle from/to appropriate points;
- add black circles to the rectangle;
- add a curved arrow with the label `s'`.

Hopefully, this should enable you to build further on what you have already.

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    triangular/.style = {regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, draw=black, fill=green!60!black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2cm},
    border rotated/.style = {shape border rotate=180},
    rectangular/.style={fill=brown!80!black, rectangle, rounded corners = 5pt, draw=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=4.5cm, minimum height=1cm},
    square/.style={fill=blue!60!black, rectangle, draw=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size = 1cm}
]

    \node[square] (1) {};
    \node[triangular, border rotated] (2) [below left = 1cm  of 1] {};
    \node[triangular, border rotated] (3) [below right = 1cm  of 1] {};
    \node[rectangular] (4) [below=3cm of 1] {};
    \node[square] (7) [below = 7cm of 1]{};
    \node[triangular] (5) [above left = 1cm  of 7] {};
    \node[triangular] (6) [above right = 1cm  of 7]{};

    \draw (2.35) -- +(0,0.2) -- (1);
    \draw (2.145) .. controls +(-7.5mm,35mm) and +(-7.5mm,-35mm) .. (5.215);
    \draw (3.145) -- +(0,0.2) -- (1);
    \draw (5.-35) -- +(0,-0.2) -- (7);
    \draw (6.-145) -- +(0,-0.2) -- (7);
    \draw (3.35) .. controls +(7.5mm,35mm) and +(7.5mm,-35mm) .. (6.-35);
    \draw (2.south) -- (4.north -| 2.south) (3.south) -- (4.north -| 3.south) (4.south -| 5.north) -- (5.north) (4.south -| 6.north) -- (6.north);

    \path (2.south) -- node [fill, circle] {} (5.north);
    \path (3.south) -- node [fill, circle] {} (6.north);
    \draw [<-] (4.north west) [bend right] to ++(-10mm,10mm) node [anchor=south] {$s'$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: connections]

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I can see why the code or the syntax work. But without you telling me how exactly, I would now know them at all.